# How does one account for uncertainty in the independent variable when calculating the uncertainty of a fit

Tags: error, curve-fitting, uncertainty, measurement, calibration

I am calibrating on sensor to another, measuring the same unit (temperature), over a range of values. The independent variable (accurate sensor) has a known uncertainty from a calibration sheet. I can calculate the standard error of the fit, $s_{yx}$, but this does not take the uncertainty of the accurate sensor into account.

$$
s_{yx}=\sqrt{\frac{\sum{y_i-y_{ci}}}{v}}
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would account for that using a [errors-in-variables models or measurement error model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Errors-in-variables_models). This can be quite tricky to deal with. One possible approach - especially when you have prior information on the measurement uncertainty in the variable - is to use a Bayesian approach. E.g. basic usage in the brms R package is shown [here](http://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/me.html) and there's more discussion explaining the implementation [here](https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/is-the-brms-measurement-error-model-doing-the-right-thing/9300/4).

What you'll end up doing is instead of fitting a single regression model, you fit a joint model for your main regression of interest and also the measurement process (plus possibly for what the distribution of covariates is).